# How to implement Singleton when the constructor may throw a checked exception

Tags: java, exception, constructor, singleton

I have a checked exception named `Class1Exception`

```
public class Class1Exception extends Exception {
   ...
}
```

I have a class named `Class1` whose constructor may throw `Class1Exception`.

```
public class Class1 {
   public Class1() throws Class1Exception {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Now I want to implement thread-safe Singleton pattern for class `Class1`. Usually I implement Singleton by making constructor private, creating a static final variable of same type as class which also calls the constructor and then have a getInstance method to access it:

```
public class Class1 {
   private static final Class1 INSTANCE = new Class1();

   private Class1() throws Class1Exception {
      ...
   }

   public static Class1 getInstance() throws Class1Exception {
      return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Problem is this solution is not working in this case as the constructor is throwing a checked exception. Changing checked exception to unchecked is not an option. What could be the solution?

**Just to clarify: The class `Class1` cannot handle `Class1Exception` by itself. This exception is meant to be handled by any code which is calling `Class1`.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use static initilizing section:

```
private static Class1 INSTANCE; 
static {
   try { 
      INSTANCE = new Class1();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception catching
   }
}
```

**UPD** or you can wrap initilization into new method:

```
private static final Class1 INSTANCE = createInstance();

private static Class1 createInstance() {
    try {
       return new Class1();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception catching
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want `Class1` to propagate any exception thrown in its constructor to the caller of `Class1` as `Class1Exception`. The caller of `Class1` will catch `Class1Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Init your instance in a static block and wrap the constructor call in a try..catch.

   static {
      // init your instance here
   }
2. Only call the constructor lazily when the getInstance() gets called and handle the exception on every call.

Comment: Thanks. But I want `Class1` to propagate any exception thrown in its constructor to the caller of `Class1` as `Class1Exception`. The caller of `Class1` will catch `Class1Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to the static initializer block is a private static method :

```
private static final Class1 INSTANCE = initSingleton(); 

private static Class1 initSingleton() {
   Class1 result;
   try { 
      result = new Class1();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception catching
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case `Class1` has to propagate any exception thrown in its constructor or any method, to the caller of `Class1` as `Class1Exception`. The caller of `Class1` will catch `Class1Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

just use a static initializer while rethrowing your exception using ExceptionInInitializerError.

you can look it up here:
[click me](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html)

contains the following information:

Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case `Class1` has to propagate any exception thrown in its constructor or any method, to the caller of `Class1` as `Class1Exception`. The caller of `Class1` will catch `Class1Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

What about lazy initialization?

```
public class Class1 {
private static Class1 INSTANCE;

private Class1() throws Class1Exception {
    ...
}

public static Class1 getInstance() {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        try {
            INSTANCE = new Class1();

        } catch(Exception1 exc) {
            ...
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The `getInstance()` method in your example should not catch any exception; instead it should throw `Class1Exception`. Also it has to be thread-safe which it is not in your example.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is an anti-pattern. Consider using lazy initialization of resources so the exception is thrown when attempting to invoke one of the singleton's methods, instead of in the constructor where it is not clear when or where it will throw. From the Java Language Specification on static initialization:

> For static initialization (section 12.4):
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

I think it would be way more manageable this way, no?

Comment: Lazy initialization is better I agree. As @Radek gives his answer, its mostly correct (just need to take out the try catch block from `getInstance()` method and instead it should throw `Class1Exception`). But the problem is his solution is not thread-safe. I can add `synchronized` in the method definition of `getInstance()` method but that will be a performance hit. What is the better way to make it thread-safe?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to adopt two stage construction:

1. Create instance
2. Continue with construction that may throw

The caller handles any exception before calling Instance() a second time (say in a `finally` block). Because the class object was successfully created earlier in stage 1, this subsequent call is now able to return a valid instance. Of course, the second stage construction is not complete but the caller does know that through the exception mechanism.

Example C# (soz:) code:

```
private static volatile Class1 _instance = null;
private static readonly object _sync = new object();

public static Class1 Instance()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Class1();

                _instance.Init(); // can throw
            }
        }
    }

    return _instance;
}

private class Caller
{
    Class1 _class1;

    private void LoadClass1()
    {
        try
        {
            _class1 = Class1.Instance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            _class1 = Class1.Instance();
        }
    }
}
```